# Can I change the "astro" prefix in the classes generated from scoped styles?

Tags: javascript, css, configuration, astrojs, static-site-generation

I am learning astro. When I build the static website, the scoped styles get auto generated classes that have a prefix "astro". I was thinking may be I could change the prefix or remove it using astro.config.mjs or any other way.

But I could not the find the option in the offical docs. Is it possible?

I am referring to this - [scoped-styles-in-astro](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/styling/#scoped-styles)

Comment: There is an open discussion on this [issue](https://github.com/withastro/roadmap/discussions/243)